# Nancy: How to return null as JSON value?

Tags: nancy

The following code returns nothing to browser:

```
return this.Response.AsJson((object)null, statusCode);
```

There are simply no content in the response stream:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0

Comment: If your client tries to read interpret the response as JSON, they should likely get `null` anyway. (Double check)

Comment: Be sure it is not correct... $.ajax + dataType: 'json' will lead to calling of ".fail" function (not ".done"). And for example ASP.Net WebAPI works correctly and sends null.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, It's not good design idea that api returns null/empty response(with 200 OK).

I think there should be API Response Container data type. So, API response can be always not empty JSON.

And.. I found this interesting discussion in stack exchange : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199742/restful-api-design-what-should-i-return-if-there-are-no-rows

Comment: Null is not empty result, it is different thing. Regarding object... Imagine situation when you need for example GUID as result. Why do I need object with null ID property instead of null object? Regarding provided url: they talk about collection... so in that case I simply can return empty array (collection).

Comment: I prefer use API Response Container Type. The type has default fields - resultCode, errorMessage, etc. 
IMHO, even when not using container type, null result and "404 NotFound" is better.

Comment: People said "top-level JSON array is not secure", so I use always container type design.

Comment: Thank you for your post, but it is not related to my question. But about this vulnerability... It means that bad guy can access the same data as in your API response (JSON) if user will visit site of this guy. It is occurs because browser allow to call scripts in src of <script> tag. So if API method returns array object it will be treated as valid javascript and browser will execute it. But how to get data during this execution? By overridden array constructor or ____defineSetter____ method. So to prevent this vulnerability and be free to use JSON I calls only using POST method.